# Data are not transferred correctly through a FIFO

Tags: c, node.js, pipe, buffer, fifo

I am trying to transfer MP3 buffer from a C program to a node.js program using a FIFO. I am doing this through buffering a segment the MP3 in a dynamic memory and then sending it to the node.js when it's ready.

My C code

```
void send_buffer(buffer* buff)
{
    // if the buffer was not filled
    if(buff == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
//signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_IGN);
// Attempts to open connection and returns INVALID on failure
int port = open("/tmp/radio", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
if(port != -1)
{   
    // Allocates enough memory for the header that will be sent to 
    char* segment = toBYTES(buff);

    // checks if memory allocation failed   
    if(segment == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    // saving it to a file to make sure the data in the buffer is correct
    FILE* file = fopen("temp.mp3", "a");
    if(file != NULL)
    {
        fwrite(segment, buff->size, 1, file);
        fclose(file);
    }

    // writes to the node
    char* orig_segment = segment; // will point to the first element of the original buffer
    // writes to the node
    int n_bytes = 0;
    while ((n_bytes = write(port, segment, buff->size)) != buff->size)
    {
        segment += n_bytes;
    }   
    close(port);        
    free(orig_segment);
}
```

I am pretty sure the buffer data in the dynamic memory is correct because I tried writing it as shown in the code and the file plays in the media player correctly.

On the other hand my node js

```
var strict = require('use-strict');
var FIFO = require('fifo-js');
// establishing connection through the FIFO
var fifo = new FIFO("/tmp/radio");
// reading data from the fifo
fifo.setReader(function(data){
var fs = require('fs');
if(data.length != 0)
    fs.appendFile('temp.mp3', data);
});
```

I tried writing out the data received through the FIFO as well; however, unlike the c program, the media player said the file was corrupted and couldn't play it. I even checked the length of the string coming to the Node.js it was often a string of length zero. What am I missing here ? Is there any better way to transfer relatively big data from one program to another ?

Comment: (1/2) Named pipes have peculiar semantics, which may interact badly with node.js's peculiar I/O model.  Is there any way -- any way at all -- you can use a normal anonymous pipe or a plain old file instead?

Comment: (2/2) With any kind of IPC channel other than a plain file, you **must** check for and handle short writes and short reads.

Comment: The `O_NONBLOCK` is convenient in that it means the `open` doesn't block until there's a process reading the FIFO.  On the other hand, it is inconvenient — you have to check that writes don't fail, etc.  You don't pay any attention to what the `write()` writes; it is no wonder you don't get complete data.  It's perfectly plausible for it to have written what fits in the FIFO buffer (64 KiB, perhaps), and then return (because it can't write more without blocking).  I counsel against using `O_NONBLOCK`.  Regardless of whether you do use it, you must pay attention to what `write()` returns.

Comment: You test for `if (buffer == NULL)` too late, and leak a file descriptor if it is NULL.  If the segment isn't allocated, you leak a file descriptor.

Comment: yes you are totally correct. I am checking for NULL buffer to late and I already fixed it. I also handled short writes in my C program by that did not solve the problem. I updated the code will you please take another look at it?